# Python: ultrasonic to audio range

Tags: python, audio, signal-processing

I'm using Python 2.7.3 and I have a question relating to ultrasonic frequencies:

Sampling at 40MHz, I measure an ultrasonic signal that's a convolution of a 1MHz resonant frequency and an envelope - The envelope of which depends on the media through which ultrasonic signal travels. I would like to listen to this received signal, my question is:

How may I map the received signal into the range of human hearing? Or put another way,
How may I down-sample and convert this signal to an audio frequency (keep the envelope shape and maybe even elongate the time so it’s longer).

Simulated signal here, but its typically like this in any case:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt

# resonant frequency is 1MHz
f     = 1e6
Omega = 2*np.pi*f

# samle at 40MHz or ts=25ns, for about 1000 samples: 
t = np.arange(0,25e-6,25e-9)
y = np.sin(Omega*t) * (t**2) * np.exp(-t/3e-6)
y /= max(y)

plt.plot(y)
plt.grid()
plt.xlabel('sample')
plt.ylabel('value')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: is the waveform always a sine with constant frequency and a function envelope ?

Comment: correction to my previous comment: Yes the underlying (resonant) freq is 1MHz and the sampling freq is always 40MHz - both are constants, it is the envelope that changes depending on application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two common answers to your question:

1. Just play it at a fraction of the sampling frequency. If you play your signal back with, e.g. 44.1 kHz sampling frequency, you will have an audible tone of approximately 1000 Hz and signal length of roughly 20 ms. (I picked 44.1 kHz as it is certainly one of the frequencies any hw can play back.) This is probably easiest to accomplish by saving your signal into a WAV file (see the `wave` module) and then you may play it back with anything that plays WAV files.
2. The standard method would be to mix the resonant frequency down to audible frequencies. This is the fundamental thing in radios. Mathematically it involves multiplying by a carrier frequency which is close to the resonant frequency, and then low-pass filtering the result. The operation can also be viewed as shifting the frequency spectrum closer to 0. However, as your signal envelope is very fast (0.25 ms), this would only result in a short click and thus not be useful here.

Other solutions can be figured out, if there are further requirements. The envelope frequency and the resonant frequency seem to be relatively close to each other, which limits the options. If you need to do this for a real time signal, then the challenge will be elongating the envelope, because then the envelope has to be detected. Otherwise it is not possible to stretch the time.

Answer (score -1):

I wanted to make this a comment, but I have some examples.
There would be many ways to represent this. You could use sound as an encoding medium.
If your original waveform has few properties, like `frequency` (constant), and `envelope` (variable/can be approximated), you can for example encode the frequency in a binary form with a short sequence of sounds and silence (`1=generate sound/0=generate silence`), you could then represent the amplitude with a constant sound with variable frequency (ex. a 100Hz sound would represent a 0 amplitude, and a 10000Hz sound would represent max amplitude). To rebuild the original envelope, you could use interpolation.
I hope you see my point.

Comment: That's an interesting idea - Do you have 'starter code' to implement this?